# lambda function uses its parameter as template parameter calling template function

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

The following is the sample code, which cannot compile.

We use *iteration* function to iterate over some range and run the lambda callback function. The *iterate* function will pass some indications (i.e. *type*) to the callback lambda function, which will then do works based on indications. Since these indications are fixed in compile-time, I believe there is a way to remove all indication overhead in runtime. But how..?

```
template<typename FuncT>
void iterate(const FuncT& func) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        func(0, i);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        func(1, i);
}

template<int d> int getValue(int i) { return d+i; }
// this has run-time overhead compared to the template version
// int getValue(int d, int i) {return d+i; }

int main() {
    iterate([&](const int type, int index){
        // error: cannot compiler here
        // candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'd'
        std::cout<<getValue<type>(index)<<std::endl;
    });
}
```

Comment: In `getValue<type>(index)` the value of type must be known at compile time, but it is not known until the lambda is called at runtime. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @WernerHenze you're right. it is just a sample code. In my project, the parameter passed to the lambda function (i.e. type) is known at compile time. I am just wondering is there a way to remove it from runtime through template. I guess Evg gives a very cool solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a run-time variable as a template parameter, which should be a compile-time constant. But you can wrap constants into [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) to encode a constant value into a type:

```
template<typename Func>
void iterate(Func func) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        func(std::integral_constant<int, 0>{}, i);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        func(std::integral_constant<int, 1>{}, i);
}

template<int d>
int getValue(int i) {
    return d + i;
}

int main() {
    iterate([&](auto type, int index) {
        std::cout << getValue<type>(index) << std::endl;
    });
}
```

`std::integral_constant` can be implicitly converted into a value of underlying type. In `getValue<type>(index)`, `type` is converted into the wrapped value of type `int`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/QJmp8m)